# Data not being retrieved after upgrading to hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, jpa

After upgrading Hibernate3 to hibernate 4.3.8 and JPA 2.0 to JPA 2.1, the pet list is being not retrieved if a pet has temperament as null (using lazy loading).
Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

what i tried is I dont no what to try..tried replacing the joincolumn annontation by @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pet") but got some other mapping error.

temperament have foreign key relation with PetTemperament

The query fired using Hibernate 4 and JPA 2.1 is

```
select *
from OwnerPet ownerpets0 
inner join Pet petmodel1 on ownerpets0.petId=petmodel1.id 
inner join PetTemperament pettempera3 on petmodel1.temperament=pettempera3.id 
where ownerpets0.ownerId=144
```

The query using Hibernate 3 and JPA 2.0

```
Select *  from OwnerPet ownerpets0 
inner join Pet petmodel1 on ownerpets0.petId=petmodel1.id 
left outer join PetTemperament pettempera3 on petmodel1.temperament=pettempera3.id 
where ownerpets0.ownerId=144
```

Pet is joined to PetTemperament using

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column
public Integer getTemperament() {
    return temperament;
}
public void setTemperament(Integer temperament) {
    this.temperament = temperament;
}


@ManyToOne()
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name="temperament", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public PetTemperamentModel getPetTemperament() {
    return petTemperament;
}

public void setPetTemperament(PetTemperamentModel petTemperament) {
    this.petTemperament = petTemperament;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You marked `temperament` join column with `nullable=false`, that's the reason Hibernate uses `inner join`. If, as you say, there are pets in database with `null` temperament, try removing `nullable` constraint and you should be ok.

Comment: yess..it worked..thank you so much..:)..so just to summarise "Hibernate will use inner join if foreign key columns are null"..right??

Comment: If you mark foreign columns as `not null`, to Hibernate it means the relation has to exist and no data will be lost if inner join is used. So, you just need to keep your data model and Hibernate annotations in sync (don't mark it as `nullable = false` if you allow `null` values in database).